# How to convert Var to int[] in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagridview

I am using linq to get column values from datagridview. Once I have the column values(numeric), I then want record count based on range
Here is my code -

```
var column_values = radGridView1.Rows.Cast<Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo>().Select(r => r.Cells["columnName"].Value);

int count = 0;
foreach(int i in columnvalues.ToList()){
 if(i > 0.1 and i < 0.5) {
    count++
}
}
```

But I am getting this error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collection.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type
>   system.IConvertible'.

I know that the foreach condition is wrong but can't figure it out. The numbers could also be decimal.

Also is there a direct way to do this using the linq instead of using for loop.

Please help.

Comment: how can a number be lower than 10 and higher than 50 at the same time?

Comment: Is `columnvalues` meant to be the same as `column_values`? Did you bother to find out the actual runtime type of the contents of either one?

Comment: The variable name is typo, but in actual code it is correct. Also, all values are decimal values.

Comment: if you have only decimal values in your list, then cast the _Value_ object directly to a _decimal_ ... `var column_values = radGridView1.Rows.Cast<Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo>().Select(r => (decimal)r.Cells["columnName"].Value);` and after that you can get the _Count_ like so `var count = column_values.Count(_ => _ > 0.1 && _ < 0.5);`

Comment: It gives specified casting was not correct error at Var count = ...

Comment: Please post us the values from the *column_values*.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are actually int, you can use `.Cast()`:

```
foreach (int i in columvalues.Cast<int>())
```

If they're strings, you can parse them:

```
foreach (int i in columvalues.Select(int.Parse))
```

Comment: I am getting error - "specified cast is not valid with Cast." The values are actually decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Select to use int.Parse:

```
Select(r => int.Parse(r.Cells["columnName"].Value.ToString()));
```

Then you can iterate over integers, no need for `ToList`:

```
foreach(var i in columnvalues)
```

Also you can get rid of `foreach` by using `Count` method:

```
var count = radGridView1.Rows.Cast<Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo>()
                   .Select(r => int.Parse(r.Cells["columnName"].Value))
                   .Count(x => (your condition));
```

I leave the condition part to you because the condition you got there will never be `true`.

Comment: I am getting error cannot convert obj to string here - int.Parse(r.Cells["columnName"].Value)

Comment: @jamesandy Add `.ToString()` after `Value`.

Comment: I get error "Input string was not in correct format" -                                  var count = radGridView1.Rows.Cast<Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo>()
                .Select(r => int.Parse(r.Cells["column name"].ToString()))
                .Count(x => x < 0.1);

Comment: well then you don't have valid integer values in the column or some of them are null or empty.

Comment: There are no null or empty values. The values are all decimal.